# Firebase authentication and database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want use firebase authentication and get the Uid and stock it with other informations about user in firebase Database.

I have SignUpActivity and LoginActivity ,i'm using firebase authentication(email , pwd ) to sign up and sign in my app, and it's fine, but when i 'm adding some more informations about user like firstName,lastName,phoneNumber, i have an err "NullpointerException" at authUser

SignUpActivity, ButtonSignUp:

```
 btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final String nom =inputNom.getText().toString().trim();
                final String prenom=inputPrenom.getText().toString().trim();
                final String numTel= inputNumTel.getText().toString().trim();
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                //create user
                authUser.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(SignupActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    createUser(nom,prenom,numTel);
                                    Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        });

            }
        });


             private void createUser(String nom, String prenom,String numTel) {

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        authUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = authUser.getCurrentUser();

        if (user != null) {
            id=user.getUid();
        }
        userInfos = new User(nom, prenom, numTel);
        myRef.child(id).setValue(userInfos);

    }
```

This is the logcat and the Debugger:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using a different name for the instance of Firebase in the createUser method, I suggest declaring a local variable within the method.

Secondly, the if statement below will always evaluate to 'false' if the user registration is successful and true when the registration, for any reason, fails, so remove the '!':

```
 if (!task.isSuccessful()) 
 {
  createUser(nom,prenom,numTel);
  Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Authentication failed." +  
   task.getException(),
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Post your error log as well, could help understand the error better. Hope this helps.

-------Code Snippet below, modify it as needed.-------

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth fbAuth;
    private EditText userNameField;
    private EditText passwordField;
    private EditText emailField;
    private Button registrationButton;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        //initialize all variables/objects
        fbAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users"); 
        userNameField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameField);
        passwordField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
        emailField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailField);


        registrationButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.registerButton);

        registrationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            startUserRegistration();
            }
        });

    }

    private void startUserRegistration() {
         //initialize all variables/objects
        FirebaseAuth fbAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        final String name = userNameField.getText().toString().trim();
        String email = emailField.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = passwordField.getText().toString().trim();

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
        {



            fbAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {


                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                      //your logic is below, initialize the user object  
                    user = authUser.getCurrentUser();   

        if (user != null) {


        String userid = fbAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        userInfos = new User(nom, prenom, numTel);
        myRef.child(id).setValue(userInfos);

            }

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did what u tell me but i still have the same err , I just add the logcat above.

Comment: What is on line 121?

Comment: There is :  authUser.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

Comment: That means you have not initialized the authUser object correctly, or it is out of scope at line 121. I will edit my answer earlier and post some code that you can use to implement basic user registration. Let me know is that helps.

Comment: Yes indeed I thought I have a problem in CreateUser (), but in fact I had to get Firebase auth instance in onCreate().